# MagicOnion on Unity3D, .dll file ChannelBase is missing shutdownasync functions

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, grpc

I've been trying to correct an error in the script GrpcChannelx, when it references as override the methods in ChannelBase ShutdownAsync and ShutdownAsyncCore the script can't find them, when I go to ChannelBase both methods aren't there and I can't seem to add them, not even with updates and grpc packages.

I need to find a way to make ChannelBase have those methods, is there a way I can modify this? how should I go on about this?

What I did:
I added the packages as I did in the example expecting to have the functions on ChannelBase.I followed the steps in this link.

https://9to5tutorial.com/unity-net-core-magiconion-v3-environment-building-hands-on

What I got:
They aren't there and I can't seem to find a way to add them.

Comment: The base classes are generated by the gRPC compiler protoc (which is installed in point 2.4 in the linked article), which is normally called during build time. I didn't try it out, but just looking quickly at the linked article I don't see where protoc ever gets called to create the classes. Can also be that they are generated in the wrong location and they are there but just not found. Maybe this info helps you.

Comment: @dan-kli the problem is the class ChannelBase doesn't have the needed methods for magiconion, it's updated and the classes are created where they should. I can't seem to modify the channelbase script not even replacing the .dll file because it changes and removes the methods shutdownasync and shutdownasynccore